# Python: converting list of strings into a string which illustrates the list

Tags: python, string, list

I'm searching a simple method for converting a list of strings (e.g. `['test 1', 'test 2' , 'test 3']` )  into a string whereby the list of objects doesn't have some quotation mark. That means in our example (`'[test 1, test 2, test 3]'`). My first approach was:

```
import json
A = ['test 1', 'test 2' , 'test 3']
test = json.dumps(A).replace('"', '')
```

Is their a more general way without that replace statement at the background? Cause my problem with that is, that e.g.

```
A = ['test 1', 'test 2' , 'test 3"AA"']
```

results in the string:

```
   '[test 1, test 2, test 3\AA\]'
```

and not the desired string:

```
'[test 1, test 2, test 3"AA"]'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `f-strings`:

```
>>> print(f"'[{', '.join(A)}]'")
'[test 1, test 2, test 3"AA"]'

# OR

>>> print(f"[{', '.join(A)}]")
[test 1, test 2, test 3"AA"]
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way you could try would be

```
A = ['test 1', 'test 2' , 'test 3"AA"'] #your list
print (*A, sep =', ')
```