# Best way to convert dictionary in string and remove quotes (" or ') around values

Tags: python, dictionary, quotes

I have some dictionary of form:

```
Test = {'∧I': '([A, B] ⊦ ("A"∧B))', '∧E 1': "([(A∧B)] ⊦ 'A')", '∧E 2': '([(A∧B)] ⊦ B)'}
```

is their a simple way to convert it into some string without the '' around the values, means:

```
{'∧I': '([A, B] ⊦ ("A"∧B))', '∧E 1': ([(A∧B)] ⊦ A), '∧E 2': ([(A∧B)] ⊦ B)}
```

The problem with:

```
str1 = f'{Test}'.replace('"','')
```

itself is that the dictionary itself uses " or ' inside some strings.

I posted some similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70904933/python-converting-list-of-strings-into-a-string-which-illustrates-the-list) with lists. But unfortunately its a little bit difficult to transfer it on dictionaries.

Comment: `str1` is not a string but just an invalid expression and has unbalanced single quotes at `([A, B] ⊦ ("A"∧B))'`. Could you make sure of your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_ = "{" + ", ".join([f"{k}: {v}" for k, v in Test.items()]) + "}"`